# android how to get indicate when the internet connection is lost?

Tags: android, android-networking, android-internet

I'm developing an android application and I want to get a notification when the internet (wifi or packet data connection) connection is lost. On my approach I can get the status of the connection as:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

while having this in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

How could I be notified automatically when the connection is lost?

Comment: The above code is the standard way to check whether there is internet or not, so what is your question?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119607/how-to-be-notified-on-wifi-network-status-change

Comment: @user2310289 : its need to  call the `isNetworkAvailable();` method to get to know the connection status. its ok when app starting. but while app running its not much good way to handle the requirement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For WIFI you could register a broadcast receiver as:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

You can also register the receiver in the Manifest.

Then in your receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false)){
            //do stuff
        } else {
            // wifi connection was lost
        }
    }
}
```

For any type of data connection listeners you could use the following receiver registered as:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.ConnectivityReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and the in your `ConnectivityReceiver`:

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

In the `onReceive` method you could check if you have internet connectivity or not using [this developer article](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

Comment: could you please explain `registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);`

Comment: You can use `registerReceiver` if you're interested to be notified on the life-time of an `Activity`/`Service`. Otherwise you're registering a `BroadcastReceiver` directly in the manifest and so you're getting the updates all the time, no matter if the application is running or not. [`registerReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter)) is available in the `Context` class. Just don't forget to call unregisterReceiver if you registered in a `Context` class.

Comment: does this also work when mobile data connection is lost?

Comment: This intent action/constant was deprecated in API level 28.

Answer (score 5):

use following code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import classes.NetworkUtil;

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

            boolean IsConnected = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
           // Toast in here, you can retrieve other value like String from NetworkUtil
           // but you need some change in NetworkUtil Class
        }
    }
```

and `NetworkUtil` is:

```
package classes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkUtil {

    public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        } 
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }

    public static boolean getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        boolean status = false ;
        if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            status = true;
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            status = true; 
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

and in manifest file:

```
 <receiver
            android:name="receiver.NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and this permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: This is deprecated for apps targeting N and higher. In general, apps should not rely on this broadcast and instead use JobScheduler.

Comment: Yes you right, you must use JobScheduler, WorkManager, or register broadcast programmatically  @c-an, I wrote this answer in 2014

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a broadcast receiver.

Add these as intent filters.

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score -3):

You should use [BroadcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for your requirement. Create a BroadcastReceiver which listen for network changes.

Incase of any change in the network it will automatically fire the event and you can perform your operations regarding it.