# Conditioned Data Connection

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

How can I programmatically check that internet access in a android device is only over `Wi-Fi` and not over `Packet Data` connections like `UMTS` `EDGE` or `GPRS` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want your app to only use one particular type of data connection, you can form if/else logic and use check for mobile-network-access and wifi-access and give command accordingly

you can refer to  [mobile-network-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806709/android-how-to-tell-if-mobile-network-data-is-enabled-or-disabled-even-when) and [wifi-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409169/how-to-know-when-the-user-turn-on-off-mobile-data-or-wifi) questions of stackoverflow for check on connection availability