# Android: onConnectionToInternet

Tags: java, android, internet-connection

I want to know if there any listener, like `onClickListener` , but for **connection to the Internet.** I want to start some function, only when there is a new connection to Internet.
Exactly like a Button, that till it is not pressed, it's not start the `onClick`.

Does someone know something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Devrath how BROADCAST RECEIVER could help me?

Comment: See this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out **[BROADCAST RECIEVER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)**

- What happens is as soon if a change in network ex:`Internet`, android
  fires an intent
- You can use this Intent as per your wish to achieve your objective,
  like performing some tasks
- You can place the `Broadcast reciever` in your main activity
- Don't forget to declare it in `manifest`

[***CHECK THIS STACKOVERFLOW POST***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21226812/1083093)- IT WILL GIVE YOU THE IDEA ON HOW TO USE

**Hope this helps !**, ***comment back if you need any more information***

Comment: Thanks for reply! How can I get that intent? Do yo have any examlpe code for that?

Comment: Check the edit ...... it shows on how to do it for wifi .... its similar to internet too .... google for some tutorials ..... its very simpe .... let me know my answer helps to clear your query !

Comment: @Itay .... Were you able to get answer to your question ? .... Check the answer correct if it helps so that it will be helpful to others who come across similar problem !

Comment: I'll check that tomorow :) I just discovered some other problems in my app ^^

Comment: Is there any way do it it on service?