# Firebase update user's status

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've read [Offline Capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) on Firebase Docs and it wasn't helpful enough.

The thing that I want to do is if user goes offline I want to set status offline. The problem is if user lost connection, user won't be able to update the status.

Comment: where are you doing it? You can find out with the user lost connection and then run code in there.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/21226812/8200290

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read carefully the section of that page called [Presence Management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence).  It describes how to use an onDisconnect handler to change a location of the database when the app loses its connection.

For example, to set the location "disconnectmessage" to the value "I disconnected!" when the connection is lost:

> ```
> DatabaseRef presenceRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("disconnectmessage");
> presenceRef.onDisconnect().setValue("I disconnected!");
> ```

Comment: It works well but when I cut my internet connection, it does not work. How can I solve this?

Comment: The server may take a few minutes before it detects that the connection has disappeared. It depends on the socket timing out.