# How to get notified when the users Wifi changes from one network to other

Tags: java, android, wifi

I have an app in which I need to detect users Wifi connection and based on that, the user can see some data. The point is that I want to get notified when the user was on some other network while starting the app and moves to some other network while the app was running. Let me make a scenario:

Suppose I have 2 wifi, one inside my house and other outside. When starting the app, I was inside the house and accordingly the data shown to me was "ABC". Now when I move outside the house, my app should give a notification and kill the activity and hence I should not be able to see the same data "ABC" when I am outside the house.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to be notified on wifi network status change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119607/how-to-be-notified-on-wifi-network-status-change)

Comment: hi akshat a code snippet is at answer please have a look, hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Write a BroadcastReceiver as follows

  ```
  public class TheBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
  {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
      {
          WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                  .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          NetworkInfo datainfo = intent
                  .getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
          if (datainfo != null) 
          {
              if (datainfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) 
              {
                  //have different network states here
                  if (datainfo.getState() == datainfo.State.CONNECTING || datainfo.getState() == datainfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                      //work accordingly
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Register a BroadcastReceiver and register these entries at manifest

  ```
      <receiver android:name="yours package details like com.a.b.c.TheBroadcastReceiver " >
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
                 <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
             </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
  ```
- Add following permission sets at manifest

  ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
  ```
- Also visit http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: Hi Jitesh, thanx for the help but can you tell me where I will be notified that the Wifi has been changed. I mean suppose I am on wifi named "Inside", and I move to "Outside", can you please tell me where to write the code to toast a message like "Wifi has been changed from "Inside" to "Outside"."

Comment: hi i wrote  a comment on given code as //work accordingly..there you need to work accordingly

Comment: And what is the section in which there is "//have different network states here".? What network states does it mean.?

Comment: as you can see there is a if checking after it and it is anside after checking for wifi state ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI!!

Comment: basically you are getting  different network states after that comment, please see the code

Comment: @Kedarnath thankyou for editing and pointing it correctly. i added you on g talk as you have given mail id at yours profile

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay ok, will talk with you in evening time.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the user changes the connection you can catch in BroadcastReceiver.

- First of all you require to declare following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
  ```
- Create a BroadcastReceiver

  ```
  public class BrodcastNetwork extends BroadcastReceiver 
  {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
                // Write your code here
        }
  }
  ```
- Apply the filters to BroadcastReceiver

  ```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.datausage.BrodcastNetwork" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Register a broadcast receiver to listen for the Action "android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION"
2. When connection changed to "connected" state, call WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID() to check the current access point ID