# How to auto connect app to home network when on wifi?

Tags: android, ios, raspberry-pi

I am developing an application on Rasberry Pi, by running a lamp server. I would basically want the app (Android/iOS) to connect to the local sever directly when on WiFi.

I am not able to figure out if there is a way to get this done?

Regards,
Ayush

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3122731/1532168). It explains how to listen for state changes of the wifi adapter in android. From there you could trigger some actions in your app.
The same should be possible in iOS.

Comment: What do ou mean "connect directly"?  Do you want to use a different server when not on wifi?

Comment: Yes when not on wifi, I would probably connect via a cloud server to the local raspberry lamp server.

Comment: @cgross is there a quick way to detect the IP address of the raspberry pi server.

Comment: I would suggest you give it a static IP so you don't have to search for it in the network.